# locating path of a file in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, coffeescript, npm

I have a project in meteorjs that is using the nodes filesystem to read file, but I am not able to locate the file to be read.

My file Location

```
Server
    - startup
         - app.load.coffee
         - myfileToBeRead.txt
```

My try in app.load.coffee

```
fs = Npm.require('fs')
console.log fs.readFileSync 'server/startup/myfileToBeRead.txt'
```

I am not able to read the file as it says

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'server/startup/myfileToBeRead.txt'
```

I think since meteor merges everything in a js file, I have to add full path to the file.
I have tried other paths aswell (with the full path, without the full path). Can you point me out to the correct direction here?
Thank you

Comment: Do you want `myfileToBeRead.txt` to be checked into your repo, or does it necessarily need to be independent from your project?

Comment: I would like it to be checked into the repo, but can you give me the solution of independent aswell as well as checked one?

Comment: I am really confused about the file management system in meteor now. I can't even write to any file. Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if the file should be checked in**

This is the easy case - just place the file in your `private` directory and access it with the [assets api](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/assets_getText). For more examples, see [my blog post](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/get-text) on exactly this subject.

**if the file should exist somewhere else on the server**

Use an absolute path to a directory not associated with your project, e.g. `/tmp` or `/home/foo/bar`. Directories inside of a meteor project get jumbled up after you bundle and deploy your app, so their existence can't be counted on. Using your example above it should work if you do something like:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
fs.readFileSync('/tmp/myfileToBeRead.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well with the answer from David, I also found that I could do this with the assets/app directory of the project. All I had to do was add the file to a directory named private. This would also help me write to a file inside the directory aswell.

```
fs = Npm.require('fs')
console.log fs.readFileSync "assets/app/myfileToBeREad", 'utf8'
```

Comment: That should work in dev mode, but does it work after your bundle your app and deploy it?

Comment: yes that wouldn't I would have to put files in private directory and use assets/app. I am new to meteor and I keep on forgetting that the project structures get destroyed after deployment. Thank you. I have changed my answer